# How do I animate a cube turning into a sphere when it is moved through a plane.

Tags: mesh

I want to create a transition between shapes when a a cube goes through flat plane and comes out a sphere but I don't know how to make it only half render.  I want to make the cube disappear as it moves through the plane.

Answer (score 6):

Parent cube and sphere to an empty. Put two additional cubes below and above the sphere. Use the upper one as a boolean to eat the cube, use the lower one to eat the sphere. Use the empty to animate them.

Here's the setting in one picture: The Empty moves cube and sphere up or down, 'cubekiller' and 'spherekiller' are simple cubes who touch each other. You can put them on a disabled layer or disable rendering in the Outliner.

[image: wire wire on the wall]

The modifier settings are straightforward

[image: modifier settings]

And the result:

[image: result]

Comment: Can you upload the .Blend you made?